# jquery mobile arrows/icons not showing on iphone app

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

This one has me wondering whats going on, has been a couple of days already..

I have been delevoping a concept app on xcode and relying on the iOS Simulator initially, then I started testing it on the iPhone ans something rather odd happens.

When I look in the simulator I have the screen:

[image]

Which is exactly how I wanted to look, but then I load it in the iPhone and I see this:
[image]

Where one can clearly see that the arrows are missing, this also happens for the header bar etc. Also the arrows seem a bit off on the iOS Simulator - this is replicable when I open the site on Chrome.

Any ideas on this issue?

Thank you again in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue was that when I updated to Jquery Mobile 1.3 (from 1.2), I didn't update the icon files in the images folder, which apparently changed a bit in this release. Now I updated them and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

On an iOS device, the file paths are case sensitive unlike on the simulator where file paths are not case sensitive. Can you check the file path references are case sensitive in your code?

Comment: I checked, they all refer to "images" in the css and everywhere, note that the images from Jquery Mobile are the ones acting weirdly..

Comment: although not tested yet, it seems to be that when I updated to jquery mobile 1.3 I forgot to copy the new images to the folder containing the old ones..I'll keep posted with news.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but think it's interesting to add that if the iPhone you're testing on is retina, you'll need the icon-36-white.png and not the icon-18-white.png.
So either you comment out the @media with pixel ratio 1.5 in jquery.mobile css or add the icon-36-white.png image to image foler and should work like a charm.